# Facebook PHP SDK Error in Wordpress

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

Hi everyone :) I want my wordpress blog to be auto-shared on my visitors timeline , so i'm adding this code below to the top of header.php . The problem is at the `'link' => '<?php the_permalink(); ?>` which turns into error . It works whenever i put an url in plain txt , i.e. http://seoshqip.com , but i want the permalink which the visitor is browsing to be posted on his wall . The demo site is http://seoshqip.com . Can anyone help me please ?

```
 <?php

  require_once('php-sdk/facebook.php');

  $config = array(
    'appId' => '137338253107187',
    'secret' => '13d3be5549ff2f2e1c793b5270a3a487',
  );

  $facebook = new Facebook($config);
  $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
  $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

      if($user_id) {

      try {
        $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST',
                                    array(
                                      'link' => '<?php the_permalink(); ?>' ,
                                      'message' => 'Posting with the PHP SDK!'
                                 ));

      } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array(
                       'scope' => 'publish_stream'
                       )); 
        header("Location: $login_url");
        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
      }   
    } else {
      $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array( 'scope' => 'publish_stream' ) );
      header("Location: $login_url");

    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `<?php echo post_permalink(); ?>` Instead. If that still doesn't work, refer to this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink

`<?php the_permalink(); ?>` must be within The Loop, and is generally used to display the permalink for each post, when the posts are being displayed. Since this template tag is limited to displaying the permalink for the post that is being processed, you cannot use it to display the permalink to an arbitrary post on your weblog. Refer to `get_permalink()` if you want to get the permalink for a post, given its unique post id.

Comment: i tried both ways man , still same "redirect loop" Error (too many redirects)